# Difference between Audiomanager and MediaPlayer

Tags: android

Can anybody explain me what's the difference between `AudioManager` and `MediaPlayer` in Android ? If I am correct, then `AudioManager` can only play audio, while `MediaPlayer` can play both audio and video. But I believe there must be more to this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AudioManager doesn't play sound at all. It provides access to sound settings, but to play sounds easily, you should use MediaPlayer, SoundPool, or possibly AudioTrack.

[From the docs:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html)

> AudioManager provides access to volume and ringer mode control.

Answer (score 4):

AudioManager is used to manage audio settings. This includes volume control and the streaming channels (e.g. ringer, media, in-call, etc.).

MediaPlayer is used for controlling the playback (e.g. stop, play, pause, etc.) of audio/video streams.